# Swift 2.0 OneSignal .pushNotification

Tags: ios, swift, api, push-notification, onesignal

Hi there i was gonna set up a func for send push notifications from app to every downloaded app when the thing i needed to trigger so the func is;

```
func notification(debug:Bool,content:String){
    let pushContent:[NSObject : AnyObject] = ["app_id" : [""], "contents": ["en": content]]

    OneSignal.postNotification(pushContent)
}
```

error is **Ambiguous reference to member 'postNotification'**

I checked the API Reference they gave a example like this that is't working as well

```
OneSignal.postNotification(["contents": ["en": "Test Message"], "include_player_ids": ["3009e210-3166-11e5-bc1b-db44eb02b120"]])
```

error is **'(dictionaryLiteral: (NSObject, AnyObject), (NSObject, AnyObject))' is not convertible to '(dictionaryLiteral: (NSString, NSObject)...)', tuples have a different number of elements**

How can i make this work ?

And yes it's up to date 
    Using OneSignal (1.13.2)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`postNotification` and most OneSignal functions are instance functions. You will need to use the same instance that was created from `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` or use the `OneSignal.defaultClient()` helper to get the current instance.

Example:

```
OneSignal.defaultClient().postNotification(["contents": ["en": "Test Message"], "include_player_ids": ["3009e210-3166-11e5-bc1b-db44eb02b120"]])
```